# Cannot run dotnet single file in Ubuntu

Tags: .net

I am not able to run my single file .net 6 app in Ubuntu.

dotnet ./AppName

The app is working normally with multiple files dotnet deployment like this (with extension .dll)

dotnet ./AppName.dll

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuzPi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Run it without `dotnet` in the front. ie just `./AppName`.